# Java 16 bit alignment

Tags: java, binary, alignment, bit

I'm currently dealing with some integer values that represent offsets within a file, the numbers I have need to be aligned on 16-bit boundaries, however I'm a little unsure how to do this.

For example:

```
First number: 89023
16-bit aligned: 89024

Second number: 180725
16-bit aligned: 180736

Third number: 263824
Already 16-bit aligned, don't need to change it.
```

This is probably my maths failing me more than anything, but if anyone could advise on how to achieve this in Java, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

**Update**

I think I've just solved it, it's just a matter of modding the value with 16, then working out what's missing from 16.

So for example:

```
180725 % 16 = 5
16 - 5 = 11
180725 aligned to 16-bits is: 180736
```

Can someone just confirm that I'm doing that correctly?

Comment: yep, you are rounding up to the next 16-bit alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that will work.  The 16 bit boundary alignment just assures it will be on a multiple of 16.  What you are doing there is ensuring that the value hits at the next value of 16, rounded up.

```
// find how far off of alignment you are, 0-15
offset = num % 16 
// determine how much further you need to move the value to achieve 16 bit alignment
// only use if offset > 0, otherwise you are already good
val = 16 - offset
```

Comment: Since 16 is a power of 2, a quicker way to achieve the same is to calculate `(num + 15) & ~16`.

Comment: @fge Actually checking the assembly, `num % 16` is transformed into `~ (~i & 15) + 16`. So, as usual, the compiler is smart enough that we don't have to bother with bitwise tricks.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities have been described in the other answer/comment. Here are the full implementations:

```
public static int getAlignment_modulus() {
    int offset = num % 16;
    int result = offset == 0 ? num : num + 16 - offset;
    return result;
}

public static int getAlignment_bitOps() {
    return (num + 15) & ~15;
}
```